# what is hex version of a programs , what is it for

Tags: c, linux, gcc

hex version of programs ,
 For example  in linux is a program is written in the form

```
char esp[] __attribute__ ((section(“.text”))) /* e.s.p
release */
= “\xeb\x3e\x5b\x31\xc0\x50\x54\x5a\x83\xec\x64\x68″
 ...........
 ......
 .....
“\xc0\x40\xeb\xf9\xe8\xbd\xff\xff\xff\x2f\x62\x69″
“\x6e\x2f\x73\x68\x00\x2d\x63\x00″
“cp -p /bin/sh /tmp/.beyond; chmod 4755
/tmp/.beyond;”;
```

Could someone explain to me what the above code does ?

Comment: looks like a buffer overflow exploit

Comment: @nlightnfotis : "what is cp -p /bin/sh /tmp/.beyond; chmod 4755
/tmp/.beyond; " means

Comment: @Kajal It copies the **basic system shell** (might be bash) in a new hidden file under `/tmp/` called `.beyond`, and then changes its ownership to be able to execute it under the current process.

Comment: @NlightNFotis  , so why dont we need a compilation ? i thought every c program needs to be compiled inorder to run.

Comment: @Kajal these are shell commands, not C source code. It's essentially the same thing you write in your command line interface.

Comment: @NlightNFotis what does char esp[] __attribute__ ((section(“.text”))) 
= “ ..." mean , i think char esp[] __attribute_ is C code

Comment: @Kajal `attribute ((section(".text")))` tells gcc to put the character array `esp` in the `.text` of the executable, that is where the program's instructions are. In essence make the array's contents program instructions, in an unorthodox way.

Comment: this question caused me such a harm that i was banned from asking questions till now , an year went off , still my ban is not lifted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have linked at is usually refered to as [shellcode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellcode)

This is raw bytes representing instructions that the computer can execute, and is usually used as payload in various attacks, such as a [buffer overflow attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow).

Answering your question about how it gets produced:

Consider this piece of code in assembly:

```
[SECTION .text]
global _start
_start:
        xor eax, eax       ;exit is syscall 1
        mov al, 1       ;exit is syscall 1
        xor ebx,ebx     ;zero out ebx
        int 0x80
```

If you assemble it you get this:

```
Disassembly of section .text:

08048080 <_start>:
 8048080:       b0 01                   mov    $0x1,%al
 8048082:       31 db                   xor    %ebx,%ebx
 8048084:       cd 80                   int    $0x80
```

The bytes you need are **b0, 01, 31, db, cd 80**. Now you can easily use it like this:

```
char shellcode[] = "\xb0\x01\x31\xdb\xcd\x80";
```

[Source](http://www.vividmachines.com/shellcode/shellcode.html)
[Another Source](http://www.safemode.org/files/zillion/shellcode/doc/Writing_shellcode.html)